# How can I not print duplicate data while exporting in excel?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to export the data in my database to excel but want to avoid duplicate date like if there are two same entries only one should be printed.

**This is what I am getting**

[image: This is what I am getting]

**This is what I need**

[image: This is what I need]

exporting in excel.

```
<?php

$DB_Server = "localhost";   
$DB_Username = "root";  
$DB_Password = '';               
$DB_DBName = "gst";         
$DB_TBLName = "form";    
$filename = "data";         

$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";

header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

$sep = "\t"; 
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this problem by not querying duplicate values from the database in the first place, e.g., by using the `distinct` keyword:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM $DB_TBLName";
# Here --------^
```

Comment: so how should i approach the problem sir?

Comment: @PratikPurohit I already gave the answer - use `select distinct`.

Comment: @PratikPurohit nobody can help you with so little information. [edit] your question and add some sample input data, the result you're getting and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: Done sir have inserted the pics for helping, please help